# jQuery: show some nodes of the parent with show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, children

In jQuery

```
var myblock = $("#mycaret");
//then myblock slighly modified by jQuery
```

with modified myblock, I'd like to do this:

to exclude  this css style `table th:first-child {display:none;}` by jQuery for all tables inside of `myblock`?

This is almost the same as

```
$("#mycaret table th:first-child").show();
```

however I need it for `myblock` variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either:

```
$('table th:first-child', myblock).show();
```

Or:

```
myblock.find("table th:first-child").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
$(myblock).find("table th:first-child").show();
```

Comment: exactly! Used .has instead of .find by mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer if it actually is answer?